# Update Store object property in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have started learning angular ngrx. I am creating a project where i need to update the object name, but i am getting error.

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'blend_name' of object '[object Object]'
at reducer**

Reducer

```
export function reducer(state = postInitialState, action: actions.Actions) {
  let index, active, list;
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.actionType.GET_PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, { products: action.payload });
    }
    case actions.actionType.UPDATE_PRODUCT_LIST: {
      list = [...state.products];
      index = list.findIndex(({ uid }) => uid === action.payload.uid);
      list[index].blend_name = action.payload.blend_name;
      return Object.assign({}, state, { products: action.payload });
    } 
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
```

Action

```
export class UpdateProductListAction implements Action {
  public readonly type = actionType.UPDATE_PRODUCT_LIST;
  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

updateState(){
  let uid = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
  let updatedObj = {
    "uid":uid,
    "blend_name":"Testing"
  }
  this.store.dispatch(new productAction.UpdateProductListAction(updatedObj));
  this.store.select(productSelector.getProductList).subscribe(
    (products:productModel.Product[])=>{
      console.log(products)
    }
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to mutate the state which is readonly:

```
list[index].blend_name = action.payload.blend_name;
```

You should do something like this instead.

```
list[index] = { ...list[index], blend_name: action.payload.blend_name };
```

Explanation:

Even tho you created a new copy of the array `list`. It still contains the objects from the state.products which are readOnly. That's why you cannot mutate the object directly.

Comment: Then how we can update @ Muhammad

Comment: As mentioned in the comment: Create a new object at the index:

list[index] = { ...list[index], blend_name: action.payload.blend_name };